# Why does this string gets printed out like this?

Tags: python

i am playing around with string formatting. And actually i trying to understand the following piece of code:

```
mystring  = "\x80" * 50;
print mystring
```

output:

```
>>> 
€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€
>>>
```

the output is one string of Euro sings. But why is this like that? This is no ASCII afaik, and the other question i am asking myself is why does it not print out the hex \x80 ? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a very thorough explanation about encoding of `\x80` by John Machin [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991660/python-postgresql-strange-ascii-utf8-encoding-error/2994258#2994258).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first question, `\x80` Is interpreted as `\u0080`. A nice explanation can be found at [Bytes in a unicode Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845842/bytes-in-a-unicode-python-string).

**Edit:**
@Joran Besley is right, so let me rephrase it:

`u'\x80'` is equal to `u'\u0080'`.

In fact:

```
unicode(u'\u0080')
>>> u'\x80'
```

and that's because Python < 3 prefers `\x` as escaping representation of Unicode characters when possible, that is as long as the code point is less than 256. After that it uses the normal `\u`:

```
unicode(u'\u2019')
>>> u'\u2019' # curved quotes in windows-1252
```

Where the character is then mapped depends on your terminal encoding. As Joran said, you are probably using `Windows-1252` or something close to it, where the euro symbol is the hex byte 0x80. In `iso-8898-15` for example the hex value is 0xa4:

```
"\xa4".decode("iso-8859-15") == "\x80".decode('windows-1252')
>>> True
```

If you are curious about your terminal encoding you can get it from `sys`

```
import sys
sys.stdin.encoding
>>> 'UTF-8' # my terminal
sys.stdout.encoding
>>> 'UTF-8' # same as above
```

I hope it makes up for my mistake.

Comment: `u"\x80" != "\x80"`  ... just a heads up ... your edited answer improves a great deal on the initial answer +1

Comment: I decided to mark this answer as correct, because it is a more detailed explanation..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your terminal encoding ... in the windows terminal that encodes to a bunch of C-cedilla's

if you want to see the "\x80" you can `print repr(mystring)`

furthermore 0x80 = 128 which is the (not ascii,since ascii only technically goes to 0x7f) value of the euro

specifically that is how "Windows-1252" encodes the euro sign (actually apparently thats how almost all the "Windows-125x" encode the euro sign)

this answer has lots more info

[Hex representation of Euro Symbol €](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640354/hex-representation-of-euro-symbol-%E2%82%AC)

furthermore you can convert it to unicode

```
unicode_ch = "\x80".decode("Windows-1252")  #it is now decoded into unicode
print repr(unicode_ch) # \u20AC  the unicode equivalent of Euro
print unicode_ch #as long as your terminal can handle it
```

Comment: Could you describe this a little bit more further? I mean okay when i print this on bash its just a block of squares. I am guessing this is unicode or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

A little tinkering in IDLE produced this output.

```
>>> a = "\x80"
>>> a
'\x80'
>>> print a * 50
€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€
>>> print a
€
>>>
```

The first thing that stands out is the '\' character. This character is used for escaping characters in strings. You can learn about escaping characters in the link below.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Changing the string slightly tells us that escaping is occurring.

```
>>> print '\x8'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

What I think is happening is the escape is causing the string to be looked up in the ASCII (or similar) table.